# Possible spam user "myopic.bones"

Tags: support, spam

A large number of posts from [myopic.bones](https://superuser.com/users/91526/myopic-bones) seem to be spam.  They include answers to the following questions:

- [Does e-mail address obfuscation actually work?](https://superuser.com/questions/235937/does-email-address-obfuscation-actually-work/316028#316028)
- [Limit Chrome's bandwidth](https://superuser.com/questions/315688/limit-chromes-bandwidth/315706#315706)
- [how to limit my bandwidth to test mywebsite / applications](https://superuser.com/questions/16081/how-to-limit-my-bandwidth-to-test-mywebsite-applications/315619#315619)
- [Is there a open source monitoring package that monitors logs for specific string patterns?](https://superuser.com/questions/316017/is-there-a-open-source-monitoring-package-that-monitors-logs-for-specific-string/316030#316030)

I've flagged all of the above posts as spam.  Can someone take care of this?

Comment: I would say that the last one is not spam - Nagios is a well known and widely used monitoring tool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The posts have been deleted.  Watching the user for now.

Comment: I suggest you also delete the other, undeleted, answer to the last question, as it's lower quality than this user's.